# Aggregate queries remove zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I need to calculate the averages of a couple of columns which range from 0 to 5. However I want to exclude the zero's from the AVG calculation.

So I have something like

```
SELECT AVG(column1), AVG(column2), AVG(column3) FROM table1
WHERE ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AVG() only counts records that are non-null.
NULLIF() will return null, when the value matches the 2nd parameter.

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(column1,0)), AVG(NULLIF(column2,0)), AVG(NULLIF(column3,0)) FROM table
WHERE ????
```

You could create a more complex AVG() by using IF(column1 IN (x,y,z), column1, NULL) within.

NOTE: If your column's data is a REAL or FLOAT, then you should ROUND() or TRUNCATE() your value within the NULLIF().  EX:

```
 AVG( NULLIF( ROUND(column1,3), 0.000 )) AS column1
```

-- JJ --

Comment: Wow very nice. As a bonus you don't have to worry about division by zero. You might want to include [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b52a5/1)

Comment: I think 0 would be stored exactly, whether as a `real` or as a `float` (thus no rounding would be needed). And the NULLIF solution is really good, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, where you sum the colummn and divide by the count of rows where the value is not equal to zero:

```
SELECT SUM(Column1) / SUM (IF(Column1 = 0, 0, 1)),
SUM(Column2) / SUM (IF(Column2 = 0, 0, 1)),
SUM(Column3) / SUM (IF(Column3 = 0, 0, 1))
FROM table1
```

Not you will also have to trap divide by zero in the denominator (which i haven't done above)...

Comment: SUM(Column1) / SUM (IF(Column1 = 0, 0, 1)) is not the average, avg = sum / count

Comment: @LuciaPasarin  `SUM(IF(Colum1=0,0,1))` is a technique for counting the non-zero rows [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35579/2)

Comment: Sure, I didn't see the 0, 0, 1 part. Too fast comment from my side, sorry!

Comment: Actually, this method has a flaw: it won't calculate the results correctly if the columns have NULLs: `10, 0, NULL` should yield `10`, but [your suggestion will yield `5`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22489).

Answer (score 0):

Since the WHERE clause excludes or includes entire rows, you'll need three different queries. You can combine them into a single query though, thanks to sub-queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table WHERE column1 != 0) as avg1, 
       (SELECT AVG(column2) FROM table WHERE column2 != 0) as avg2,
       (SELECT AVG(column3) FROM table WHERE column3 != 0) as avg3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your own averages by summing the values you care about and dividing by the count of values you care about, like so:

```
select 
  sum(case when column1 = 0 then 0 else column1 end) /
    sum(case when column1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as avg1,
  sum(case when column2 = 0 then 0 else column2 end) /
    sum(case when column2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as avg2,
  sum(case when column3 = 0 then 0 else column3 end) /
    sum(case when column3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as avg3
FROM table1
```